# Whats wrong with my attempt at JavaScript factorial?

Tags: javascript, factorial

Ive attempted to make a factorial. The code below should return 24 (4x3x2x1) however it actually returns 12.

```
const fact = (no) => {
  let no2 = no;

  if (no > 1) {
    no--;
    no2 = no2 * no;
  }

  console.log(no2);
}

fact(4);
```

Comment: Where's the second, third, fourth, etc. call?

Comment: Did you try going through it with a debugger or with pen and paper? That's a lot more efficient than asking here with no attempt to debug it yourself shown.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6q4oem9q/

Comment: The code actually returns `undefined` - you probably are looking for a `while` loop instead of an `if`?

Comment: @AndrewLi There's code and a coherent question, let's not be overly harsh in our criticisms. Maybe you could provide an answer demonstrating how to do what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! Id confused if with while

```
const fact = (no) => {
  let no2 = no;

  while (no > 1) {
    no--;
    no2 = no2 * no;
  }

  console.log(no2);
}

fact(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **if** with **while**

```
const fact = (no) => {
    let no2 = no;

    while (no > 1) {
        no--;
        no2 = no2 * no;
     }

    console.log(no2);
}


fact(4);
```